# Maven - generate war and fat jar in same module

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I need generate war and fat jar (jar with all dependencies) in same pom.
I found many similar threads on this site, but still have a problem.

In my pom I set packaging to **war** and add the **maven-war-plugin** and **maven-assembly-plugin**:

```
...
<packaging>war</packaging>
....
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ....
```

Note used **maven-assembly-plugin** version - **2.2-beta-5**. In my tests its the only version that produce the correct jar file in this configuration. Unfortunately, it also prints many "[INFO]  already added, skipping" lines and the build process takes too much time.

If I use the latest version of **maven-assembly-plugin** (2.6), there are no "already added" info prints and the build at least 3 times faster, but unlike in 2.2 version all my class files placed into /WEB-INF/classes/ folder (should be in root), so I cannon run any main class from this jar. All classes from dependency jars placed in root as expected.

Are there any plugin configuration parameters in the latest version that can help produce the correct jar?

Comment: Given that the answer below is correct IMHO you should split your project in more module. Mixing war and executable jar can lead to confusion and hard to maintain software

Comment: answer below cannot be correct as it does not produce the required result

Comment: And I do not see a reason (except probably technical issues), to spit the project to several modules just to provide different packaging - jar, war, rpm...

Comment: because more granular project are easier to mange and maintain. I mean differ struct and dependencies ( you don't need servlet specific dependencies in a user jar for example).

Comment: imho, smaller jar size do not worth the multiple modules support overhead. Note that there are other building tasks, for example it also creates rpm that should include both (war and jar) files

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to get all the classes from dependencies in your root location. Let the assembly plugin do its wonders. As far as running the main class is concerned, you can use the below code in addition to what you already have.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          [...]
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.sample.App</mainClass>    // specify your main class here.
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        [...]
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

Comment: 1. there are number "main" classes in this jar, so I cannot define it in manifest and must provide the required class in run command.
2. the plugin wonders do not work in this case, class loader translates directories in jar as package names, that obviously do not match the package name declared in file.

Comment: Try using this.  `
down vote
You should be able to do it like this:

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/whereever-you-want</outputDirectory>
</build>`

Comment: I tried, it's just change the place of created file, but not its content.  The problem is that from some reason after maven-war-plugin, the latest version of maven-assembly-plugin takes ../target/<package> (instead of ../target/classes) as classes compiled directory. Are there a parameter to set the directory explicitly?